# creating columns based on values in the hierarchical row index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a hierarchical row index

```
def stack_example():
    i = pd.DatetimeIndex([ '2011-04-04',
                          '2011-04-06',
                          '2011-04-12', '2011-04-13'])
    cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['milk', 'honey'],[u'jan', u'feb'], [u'PRICE','LITERS']])
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(12, size=(len(i), 8)), index=i, columns=cols)

    df.columns.names = ['food', 'month', 'measure']
    df.index.names = ['when']

    df = df.stack('food', 'columns')
    df= df.stack('month', 'columns')

    df['constant_col'] = "foo"
    df['liters_related_col'] = df['LITERS']*99


    return df
```

I can add new columns to this dataframe based on constants or based on calculations involving other columns.

I would like to add new columns based in part on calculations involving the index.

For example,  just repeat the food name twice:

```
df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[2011-04-04 00:00:00, 2011-04-06 00:00:00, 2011-04-12 00:00:00, 2011-04-13 00:00:00], [u'honey', u'milk'], [u'feb', u'jan']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'when', u'food', u'month'])
df.index.values[4][1]*2
'honeyhoney'
```

But I can't figure out the syntax for creating something like this:

```
df['xcol'] = df.index.values[2]*2

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mds\Anaconda2\envs\bbg27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2519, in __setitem__
        self._set_item(key, value)
      File "C:\Users\mds\Anaconda2\envs\bbg27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2585, in _set_item
        value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
      File "C:\Users\mds\Anaconda2\envs\bbg27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2760, in _sanitize_column
        value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
      File "C:\Users\mds\Anaconda2\envs\bbg27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3080, in _sanitize_index
        raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
    ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I've also tried variations like `df['xcol'] = df.index.values[:][2]*2`

Comment: You want **all** the rows in the new column to have the same value?  `df['foo'] = df.index[4][1]*2` works for me.

Comment: What does `df.index.values[2]*2` produce? Is it a series that will fit the rows of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `df.index.values[4][1] * 2`, where the value is a string (`honeyhoney`), it's fine to assign that to a column:

```
df['col1'] = df.index.values[4][1] * 2

df.col1

when        food   month
2011-04-04  honey  feb      honeyhoney
                   jan      honeyhoney
            milk   feb      honeyhoney
                   jan      honeyhoney
```

In your second example, though, the one with the error, you're not actually performing an operation on a single value:

```
df.index.values[2]*2

(Timestamp('2011-04-04 00:00:00'),
 'milk',
 'feb',
 Timestamp('2011-04-04 00:00:00'),
 'milk',
 'feb')
```

You *could* still smush all that into a string, or into some other format, depending on your needs:

```
df['col2'] = ''.join([str(x) for x in df.index.values[2]*2])
```

But the main issue is that the output of `df.index.values[2]*2` gives you a multi-dimensional structure, which doesn't map to the existing structure of `df`.

New columns in `df` can either be a single value (in which case it's replicated automatically to fit the number of rows in `df`), or they can have the same number of entries as `len(df)`.

**UPDATE**
per comments

IIUC, you can use `get_level_values()` to apply an operation to an entire level of a `MultiIndex`:

```
df.index.get_level_values(1).values*2

array(['honeyhoney', 'honeyhoney', 'milkmilk', 'milkmilk', 'honeyhoney',
       'honeyhoney', 'milkmilk', 'milkmilk', 'honeyhoney', 'honeyhoney',
       'milkmilk', 'milkmilk', 'honeyhoney', 'honeyhoney', 'milkmilk',
       'milkmilk'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: What I meant was I couldn't figure out a 'vectorized' way to to get the unique `df.index.values[N][1] * 2` for  each row 'N' in the index

Comment: See updates, I think I understand what you're going for now.  Consider updating your question, it's not clear this is what you want.